# Trying to split a long String into List ( which each var in the list represent a word) using Python

Tags: python-2.7, list

Given (for example):

```
text = "Hello world            Hello    Stack"
```

I need to make a list which contains each word (only) in **text**.
The list should look like:

```
the_list = ["Hello","world","Hello","Stack"]
```

I tried to do that by

```
the_list = text.split(' ')
```

Of course, it doesn't work.
Can someone explain me what should I write in order to get the ideal list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're very close. You can just call text.split without any arguments and it should work.

```
text = "Hello world            Hello    Stack"
the_list = text.split()
```

Comment: Wow! I didn't know it.It is actually that simple. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

*using regex library we can achieve you want to get*

```
import re
text = "Hello world            Hello    Stack"
answer = re.sub("[^\w]", " ",  text).split()
```

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions would work in this case

```
text = "Hello world            Hello    Stack"

import re
my_list = re.sub(r'\s+', ' ', text).split(' ') #replacing one or more whitespaces with a single whitespace
print my_list #prints ['Hello', 'world', 'Hello', 'Stack']
```

Answer (score 0):

Works fine on Python 3

```
text = "Hello world            Hello    Stack"
the_list = []
t = ''
count = 0
for char in text:
    count += 1
    if len(the_list) > 0 and the_list[len(the_list) - 1] == ' ':
        del the_list[len(the_list) - 1]

    t += char

    if char == ' ' or count == len(text):
        the_list.append(t)
        t = ''

print(the_list)
```